# Rails - how to protect against sql injection for a postgres find_by_sql query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sql-injection, rails-activerecord

I have the following find_by_sql query against a postgres DB:

```
pick_ids = picks.pluck(:id).join(',')

Pick.find_by_sql("WITH cte1 AS (SELECT DISTINCT user_id, state, pick FROM picks 
WHERE id IN (#{pick_ids})), cte2 AS (SELECT user_id, coalesce(sum(amount_won), 0)
as picks_total_won FROM picks WHERE id IN (#{pick_ids}) GROUP BY user_id), cte3 AS 
(SELECT user_id, COUNT(CASE WHEN state = 'won' then 1 ELSE null END) AS picks_won,
FROM cte1 GROUP BY user_id) SELECT cte2.picks_total_won, cte3.picks_won,
FROM cte2 INNER JOIN cte3 ON cte2.user_id = cte3.user_id")
```

When I try to parameterize it (i.e., ?, ?...pick_ids, pick_ids), however, I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2)
```

(1) Can you parameterize a find_by_sql query like this?  If so, how?

(2) Do you even need to worry about SQL injection if the query will never receive user-inputted params?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you might want to use a `%Q{...}` string and some formatting in your SQL to avoid an unreadable mess:

```
Pick.find_by_sql(%Q{
  WITH
    cte1 AS (
      SELECT DISTINCT user_id, state, pick
      FROM picks 
      WHERE id IN (#{pick_ids})
    ),
    cte2 AS (
      SELECT user_id, coalesce(sum(amount_won), 0) as picks_total_won
      FROM picks
      WHERE id IN (#{pick_ids})
      GROUP BY user_id
    ),
    cte3 AS (
      SELECT user_id, COUNT(CASE WHEN state = 'won' then 1 ELSE null END) AS picks_won,
      FROM cte1
      GROUP BY user_id
    )
  SELECT cte2.picks_total_won, cte3.picks_won
  FROM cte2
  JOIN cte3 ON cte2.user_id = cte3.user_id
})
```

Depending on where your `picks` come from, you might be able to avoid the interpolation completely and embed the SQL to generate the `pick_ids` (possibly using another CTE).

If you need to feed the `pick_ids` in from the outside world then you can use placeholders with [`find_by_sql`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Querying.html#method-i-find_by_sql) but the interface is a bit bizarre: you have to pass an array to `find_by_sql`:

```
Pick.find_by_sql([%Q{
  WITH
    cte1 AS (
      SELECT DISTINCT user_id, state, pick
      FROM picks 
      WHERE id IN (:pick_ids)
    ),
    cte2 AS (
      SELECT user_id, coalesce(sum(amount_won), 0) as picks_total_won
      FROM picks
      WHERE id IN (:pick_ids)
      GROUP BY user_id
    ),
    cte3 AS (
      SELECT user_id, COUNT(CASE WHEN state = 'won' then 1 ELSE null END) AS picks_won,
      FROM cte1
      GROUP BY user_id
    )
  SELECT cte2.picks_total_won, cte3.picks_won
  FROM cte2
  JOIN cte3 ON cte2.user_id = cte3.user_id
}, :pick_ids => some_array_of_ids])
```

Note the location of the `[` and `]` in the argument list.

Comment: amazing! great answer...should be useful to others

Answer (score 0):

You might also use Pick.sanitize(str) to interpolate arbitrary text.

So, ignoring for a moment all the other ways to improve the query that mu mentioned, it would be:

```
Pick.find_by_sql("WITH cte1 AS (SELECT DISTINCT user_id, state, pick FROM picks 
WHERE id IN (#{Pick.sanitize pick_ids})), cte2 AS (SELECT user_id, coalesce(sum(amount_won), 0)
as picks_total_won FROM picks WHERE id IN (#{Pick.sanitize pick_ids}) GROUP BY user_id), cte3 AS 
(SELECT user_id, COUNT(CASE WHEN state = 'won' then 1 ELSE null END) AS picks_won,
FROM cte1 GROUP BY user_id) SELECT cte2.picks_total_won, cte3.picks_won,
FROM cte2 INNER JOIN cte3 ON cte2.user_id = cte3.user_id")
```